# Can you use .index for 2D arrays (without using numpy)?

Tags: python, arrays

So I've been tring to use `.index` with 2D arrays just so I can do some tests on my code, but it just comes up with an error saying that the value which is in the list actually isn't.
For example, from one project (where i was trying to revise network layering whilst practicing some coding), I tried doing this but didnt work:

```
answers = [['Application Layer','HTTP','HTTPS','SMTP','IMAP','FTP'],['Transport Layer','TCP','UDP'],['Network Layer','ARP','IP','ICMP'],['Data Link layer']]
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

qs = answers[randint(0,3)][0]
print(answers.index(qs))
print(qs)
```

[Example from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybc0c.png)

As you can see, I'm trying to get back the value of 'qs' by using index but no luck.

I've seen a few other posts saying to use numpy, but how would I do this without using numpy?

Comment: these are not arrays, these are lists

Comment: "but it just comes up with an error saying that the value which is in the list actually isn't. " no, that error is absolutely correct, that value is not in the list

Comment: So I tried making qs be 'Application Layer', which should be [0][0] but the error still showed saying it was not there

Comment: Right, *because that isn't inside your list*. There are no stings in that list, only other lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
answers = [['Application Layer','HTTP','HTTPS','SMTP','IMAP','FTP'],['Transport Layer','TCP','UDP'],['Network Layer','ARP','IP','ICMP'],['Data Link layer']]
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

qs = answers[randint(0,3)][0]

for i, answer in enumerate(answers):
    if qs in answer:
        print(i)
        break

print(qs)
```